# Getting a ConnectionClosedException with Http.Core talking to Http.Client 4?

Tags: java, sockets, java-7, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying my hand at using  http.core & client 4.3.  In general it works well, and is quite pleasant to deal with.  However, I am getting a `ConnectionClosedException` on one of my transfers and I can't see why.  Others work just fine as far as I can tell.

Everything follows the examples in a pretty straight forward way.  If it didn't, it was re-written to as much as possible in an effort to get rid of this.

1. There are 2 servers, both running the same code [A & B]
2. A `HttpClient` sends a request "AX" (POST) to B
3. B `HttpService` receives the "AX" post, processes it
4. B `HttpClient` sends a reply "BR" (POST) to A on a different port

   1. Later This should happen after the connection to A is closed, or as close as possible
   2. Right now the code doesn't actually care
5. A receives the reply from B (on a different thread) and does things

In the problem scenario, **A** is running as the server, and B is sending a POST.  Sorry it isn't always clear, since in one transaction both sides end up running server and client code.

1. **A** Sends POST to **B:8080**. Get back a proper response inline, everything ok.
2. POST Connection to **B:8080** gets closed properly
3. **B** sends new POST (like an ACK) to **A**  (ex... **B:53991** => **A:9000**).

   1. **A** Processs everything.  No issues
   2. **A** rasies ConnectionClosedException

Since I don't why it's happening for sure, I tried to put everything I think is relevant in there.  My only thought right now is that it has something to with making sure I add/change connection control headers, but I can't see how that would affect anything.

**Stack Trace** from machine "A", when the reply from B comes

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Client closed connection
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnection.receiveRequestHeader(DefaultBHttpServerConnection.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:307)
    at com.me.HttpRequestHandlerThread.processConnection(HttpRequestHandlerThread.java:45)
    at com.me.net.http.HttpRequestHandlerThread.run(HttpRequestHandlerThread.java:70)
com.me.ExceptionHolder: Client closed connection
    at com.me.log.Log.logIdiocy(Log.java:77)
    at com.me.log.Log.error(Log.java:54)
    at com.me.net.http.HttpRequestHandlerThread.run(HttpRequestHandlerThread.java:72)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Client closed connection
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnection.receiveRequestHeader(DefaultBHttpServerConnection.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpService.handleRequest(HttpService.java:307)
    at com.me.net.http.HttpRequestHandlerThread.processConnection(HttpRequestHandlerThread.java:45)
    at com.me.net.http.HttpRequestHandlerThread.run(HttpRequestHandlerThread.java:70)
```

This is the code running on **B**, the "client" in this scenario.  It is trying to POST the reply acknowledging that the first POST from **A** was received properly.  There really isn't much to transmit, and the response should only be an HTTP 200:

```
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
    final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeaders(/* create application specific headers */);

    ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(IOUtils.toByteArray(myStream));
    post.setEntity(entity);

    ResponseHandler<Void> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
            if (!NetUtil.isValidResponseCode(response)) {
                throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected Error! Oops");
            }
            // consume the response, if there is one, so the connection will close properly
            EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
            return null;
        }
    };

    try {
        client.execute(post, responseHandler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) { 
        // logic to queue a resend for 10 minutes later.  not triggered
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

On **A**:  This is called async because the response doesn't come in over the same http connection.

The main request handler does a lot more work, but it is amazing how little code there is actually controlling the HTTP in the handler/server side.  Great library... that I am misusing somehow.  This is the actual handler, with everything simplified a bit, validation removed, etc.

```
public class AsyncReceiverHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
        // error if not post, other logic.  not touching http.  no errors
        DefaultBHttpServerConnection connection = (DefaultBHttpServerConnection) context.getAttribute("connection");
        Package pkg = NetUtil.createPackageFrom(connection); // just reads sender ip/port
        NetUtil.copyHttpHeaders(request, pkg); 
        try {
            switch (recieive(request, pkg)) {
                case EH_OK:
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
                    break;
                case OHNOES_BAD_INPUT:
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                    response.setEntity(new StringEntity("No MDN entity found in request body"));
                // bunch of other cases, but are not triggered.  xfer was a-ok
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //log
        } 
    }
    private MyStatus receiveMdn(HttpRequest request, Package pkg) throws Exceptions..., IOException {
        // validate request, get entity, make package, no issues
        HttpEntity resEntity = ((HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) request).getEntity();

        try {
            byte[] data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(resEntity);
            // package processing logic, validation, fairly quick, no errors thrown
        } catch (Exceptions... ex) {
            throw ExceptionHolder(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the request handler thread.  This and the server are taken pretty much verbatim from the samples.  The service handler just starts the service and `accept()`s the socket.  When it gets one, it creates a new copy of this, and calls start():

```
public HttpRequestHandlerThread(final HttpService httpService, final HttpServerConnection conn, HttpReceiverModule ownerModule) {
        super();
        this.httpService = httpService;
        this.conn = (DefaultBHttpServerConnection) conn;
    }
    private void processConnection() throws IOException, HttpException {
        while (!Thread.interrupted() && this.conn.isOpen()) {
            /* have the service create a handler and pass it the processed request/response/context */
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext(null);
            this.httpService.handleRequest(this.conn, context);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // just runs the main logic and reports exceptions. 
        try {
            processConnection();
        } catch (ConnectionClosedException ignored) {
            // logs error here (and others). 
        } finally {
            try { this.conn.shutdown(); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is the wrong venue for such questions. Could you please make your code available at GitHub (or similar) and post your question to httpclient-users@hc.apache.org or dev@hc.apache.org?

Comment: @oleg.  SO is a perfectly appropriate place for such questions.  I would say it is the reason there is an SO! Mailing lists are a pain, but maybe they are where the l337 hax0rs hang out these days so I need to check them out again ;) And why the hell would *anyone* make their code *available* to you? What if it is not their code, but rather an employer's.  You can't be that new this this oleg, seriously.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but where is the code for B opening a connection back to A?  Also, on which machine, A or B, are you seeing the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry @WarrenDew, I realize it's a little unclear now... The stack trace is from machine A.  The "client" in this case is "B" and the receiving server is "A".  I will see if I can re-write the question

Comment: @Andrew Backer: suit yourself.

Comment: Is that where most people discuss this httpcomponents?  Email lists are a pain, but if its really the only option I will deal with the mental overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems stupid now, and really obvious.  I ignored the issue for a while and moved on to other things, and the answer bubbled up from the subconscious, as they will.

I added this header back and it all cleared up:

```
post.setHeader("Connection", "close, TE")
```

Somehow the line to set the `Connection` header got removed, probably accidentally by me. A lot of them get set, and it was still there, just wrong in this code path.  Basically, the server expects this connection to close immediately but the header was reverting to the default `keep-alive`.  Since the client closes the connection as soon as it is done with it this was surprising the server, who was told otherwise, and rightly compliained :D In the reverse path everything was OK.

Since I had just changed the old stack to use `HttpComponents` I didn't look at headers and such, and I just assumed I was using it wrong.  The old stack didn't mind it.